# How to change boxLabel for Radio button in extjs4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

Can anybody tell me how to change boxLabel for Radio button in extjs4.1?

When I have this in the controller:

`radio3.boxLabel=year`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `radio3.boxLabelEl.update(year)`.

Comment: when i have given this  radio3.boxLabelEl.update(year) getting error caught TypeError: Cannot call method 'update' of null

Comment: What is `radio3` defined as?  It has to be set as the actual `Ext.form.field.Radio` component for this to work.